# Enable a button using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to enable a button "Save" when I click on "Edit". I am trying it like below, but nothing happens:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnEdit").click(function() {
    $("btnSave").removeProp("disabled");

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button id="btnEdit" type="button" class="btn btn-danger mt-4">Edit</button>
  <button id="btnSave" type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-4" disabled>Save</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `removeAttr()`, not `removeProp()`. Or you can use `.prop("disabled", false)` to change the state of the property, which overrides the attribute.

You also had a typo: `$("btnSave")` is missing the `#`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnEdit").click(function() {
    $("#btnSave").removeAttr("disabled");

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button id="btnEdit" type="button" class="btn btn-danger mt-4">Edit</button>
  <button id="btnSave" type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-4" disabled>Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I did the corrections but did not work. Nothing happens. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnEdit").click(function() {
    $("#btnSave").prop("disabled", false);
  });
});
```

You can also use functions instead of using the click event listener:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button id="btnEdit" onclick="disableButton(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-danger mt-4">Edit</button>
  <button id="btnSave" type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-4" disabled>Save</button>
</div>
```

and

```
<script>
  function disableEl(el) {
      el.disabled = false;
  }
</script>
```